# Generate unique alphanumeric ID such as in the UK NINO (SN-60-70-45-B) format

Tags: python

How can I generate unique alphanumeric ID such as in the UK NINO (SN-60-70-45-B) format? I want to use this ID to uniquely identify the applications and also to be able to associate these IDs to their medical, tax records and so on.

Comment: If they're meant to be for real people, why are you generating them? Or is this for test records? How "real" do they have to be? If it's just "two letters, two digits, two digits, two digits" then that's pretty easy to do... it would help if you'd explain why you've got three entirely separate tags... are you trying to do this in your database, in C# code or in Python code?

Comment: Please show examples of what you've tried, what failed, and what was expected when it failed.

Comment: i want to develop some sort of social security number system that could be use to identify individuals. The registration numbers have to be unique and in the format of the UK NINO.

Comment: Hey guys i know my question might not be clear to a lot of you. The thing is that i am really now to programming. I have fundamental knowledge of c++ and python. So i am really struggling on where to start this project.

Comment: Simplify the question by focusing the question on one of your tags. I chose Python at random. The other tags were just confusing the issue. You have been asked some very good questions about what you are trying to do here and have answered with "I am new" which is no help to anyone, least of all to you. Go through the questions you have been asked and make a serious attempt to answer them and then someone may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is for python, start here:
[uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#module-uuid)

There is most likely a nicer way to do it but this should help:

```
import uuid, re
myUID = uuid.uuid1()
myNum = str(myUID.int).replace("-", "")[:6]
myLet = re.sub('\d+', '', str(myUID)).replace("-", "")[:3].upper()
myRes = myLet[:2] + "-" + myNum[:2] + "-" + myNum[2:4] + "-" + myNum[4:6] + "-" + myLet[1:2]
print myRes
```

Live Demo:

https://repl.it/DaYP

Comment: Thanks Rizzit, that really helps. At least, i now have some where to start from. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Rizzit, i was wondering if you could help me a bit. I want the above code to meet the following condition before it runs. How can i do that?
# The first two characters can only be any of the specified letters:
[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z][A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]

# The six digit rang:
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
# Last character can only be from A - D:
[A-D ] 
The First two characters cannot be :
('BG','GB','KN','NK','NT','TN','ZZ')